# Custom font in <canvas> with IE 10

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-10

I'm using a custom font (called with @font-face in the CSS file) inside a canvas. Since the font file needs to be loaded before it can be used inside a canvas, I am running the script after window load as follows:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* Generate canvas code */
});
```

This works on every browser, except IE 10. It even works well on IE 9. The font is used in a couple of other places on the site, it always renders correctly in IE 10. When navigating the site, the font will eventually show-up inside the canvas.

The site in development can be found here: http://brunobryan.com/dev/claudecormier/

Comment: "it always renders correctly in IE 10" So what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. It always renders correctly in IE 10 elsewhere on the site, when it's used outside of a canvas. When used inside a canvas, it won't show up.

Comment: Still trying to find an answer to this. How can I detect if the font ressource is loaded before executing the script? I've read elsewhere the fonts will load if used on another element in the DOM, but it's already being used in multiple places in the page. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question. Don't use comments for that.

Comment: Please edit this question to make your problem and question clear. "It doesn't work" is **NOT** a question. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).